# Mongoid not saving hash property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid4

I'm using Rails 4 and Mongoid 4. In my app I have a model I have a hash attribute. I'm trying to update this attribute like so:

```
user = User.find(id)
user['hash_attr']['another_attr'] = another_hash
user.save
```

But the above code doesn't seem to get persisted in the database. If I print the object like so:

```
puts user['hash_attr']['another_attr']
```

I get the right result, so there's no error but I try to load the model again (after the update):

```
user = User.find(id)
puts user['hash_attr']['another_attr']
```

The attribute is not updated... I've seen [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/13/mongoid-hash-field-types-watch-out/) article but 1) is quite old so maybe there's something new on this area and 2) it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

it should be user.hash_attr['another_attr']
user.save